# Get Username from other table by author_id from another table CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP and i don't know how to connect data from two tables.

Here is my tables data

1. users

id, username, password - and so on

2. news

id, title, text, author

Now i have controller, in which I have action which gets latest news from table news

```
$this->set('n_news', $this->News->find('all', array('limit' => 10,'order' => array('News.id DESC'))));
```

And now i have array which looks like this

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'News' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'title' => 'test',
        'text' => 'test #1',
        'author' => '1',
        'date' => '2014-09-25 22:56:55'
    )
)
```

)

And now i want to display username of author (with ID 1) instead of id. How can i do it in secure and efficient way?

It would be awesome if anyone can help me. This will help me a lot in my future plans for creating my application :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join to relate these tables : [JOIN TABLES](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)

```
$joins = array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'users',
                    'alias' => 'User',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array('News.auther = User.id'
                )
            );
$allnews = $this->News->find('all', array('fields'=>array('News.*','User.username as AutherName'),'joins' => $joins,'limit' => 10,'order' => array('News.id DESC')));

$this->set('n_news',$allnews);
```